# Computer is generally slow, Applications take 10 seconds - 3 minutes to launch, websites take 5-15 seconds to load, etc

Tags: macos, mac, error, performance

I don't know why but my computer is generally slow. Some examples are:

- Applications take 10 seconds - 3 minutes to launch, depending on which application.
- Websites on the internet (all browsers) take 5 - 15 seconds to load, even though I have [this internet speed](http://www.speedtest.net/result/4736326193.png) (288 down, 112 up) (flash websites can take several minutes). I also know it's not my internet speed because it's fast on my other computers, my mobile, my dads/moms/friends/brothers/sisters etc.
- When I open a new tab in Terminal, I have to wait 5 - 10 seconds to be able to use it (it has to `login` etc,) which usually take a few milliseconds.
- Loading the contents of a directory can take 10 seconds - 5 minutes.

I have repaired my disk (no errors), reset NVRAM, reset SMC, changed harddrive. There are no weird errors in the console, and the problems do not exist on other profiles.

Some information:

No processes running at over 10% CPU, 6 GB RAM is Free, 300 GB hard drive memory is free. Macbook Pro 10,1 (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) 16 GB RAM, 2.8 GHz CPU, nVidia GeForce GT 650M/Intel HD Pro 4000. No anti-virus program, I find these useless, at least for a mac.

Comment: It might be helpful if you'd provide hardware information about your Mac. Model, OS X version, RAM, HDD or SSD and how much free space on it?  How much RAM is free when experiencing the slowness? Are you running an Anti-Virus program and if yes which one?  Have you run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and or [Apple Diagnostics](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731), whichever is applicable for your Mac?  Have you looked in Activity Monitor to see if there is any excessive load on the CPU when slow and if so what process(es) is(are) running high CPU load(s)?

Comment: The bottom line is, without additional information what you've presented thus far is not adequate to diagnose the issue. Also what exactly do you mean by "and the problems do not exist on other profiles"?  Are you talking about multiple User Accounts and this only occurs under one given User Account?

Comment: The issues does not exist on my test user account.

Comment: Have you compared the two accounts as to what is running under each account upon initial login and what's different?  Have you repaired permissions on the slow account?

Comment: It's clearly a software problem and not a hardware problem if it only occurs on your user account. I suggest backing up your data and reformatting, but then NOT loading all your data back onto the drive. Start from scratch with a clean install, then load data files manually (drag and drop directories from the external). Otherwise, if you just restore from a Time Machine backup, you will also be restoring the problem.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, until complete hardware testing is done, the HDD/SSD scanned for issues and permissions repaired if required, only then IMO can it be said "It's clearly a software problem".  That said, it certainly looks like it's a software problem and why I mention what's loading differently between the two accounts.  I'd definitely make sure I have proper backups and then disable all startup items and unnecessary services under the affected account to see if its issue can be isolated before reformatting and starting over.

Answer (score 1):

It was `curl` together with `mds` and `mdworker` that caused this. I have tried it restart the computer 10 times, 5 times with the script on and it lagged like this all the time, but when I didn't run curl it was as fast as ever. I have researched but I can't at all figure out why curl would do this.